# Arrays of Structs with arrays in it. Won't compile

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, structure

I'm having trouble with making an array of structures in C++.  For some reason,
 this won't compile.  The errors point towards the Fem structure, but blame it on missing ';' and missing headers for functions. The idea is to get an array of structs with an array and a string inside of each one.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
/* Global headers and namespace */
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

/* ================================================================ */

/* Global named constants */
const int NUM_ANSWERS = 10;
const int NUM_STRUCTS = 15;

/* ================================================================ */

/* Global type definitions */

// Two struct types, Male and Female
struct Male
{

  int maleAnswers [NUM_ANSWERS];
  string name;

};

struct Fem
{

  int femAnswers [NUM_ANSWERS];
  string name;

};

// Arrays of structs
typedef Fem FemList [NUM_STRUCTS];
typedef Male MaleList [NUM_STRUCTS];

/* ================================================================ */

/* global function prototypes */
void OutputHeader ();
void ReadFile (FemList, MaleList);

/* ================================================================ */

int main ()
{

  FemList fList; // Array of Fem structs
  MaleList mList; // Array of Male structs

  void OutputHeader ();
  void ReadFile (fList, mList);

}

void OutputHeader ()
{

  cout << "==================================================================" << endl;
  cout << "Welcome to the Cheap & Ineffective Dating Service of Tallahassee!" << endl << endl;
  cout << "                       eDisHarmony.com" << endl;
  cout << "==================================================================" << endl << endl;
  cout << "<><><> Initial Client Data as Input <><><>" << endl << endl;
  cout << setw(11) << "Sex" << setw(31) << "Answers" << "Name" << endl;
  cout << setw(11) << "---" << setw(24) << "-------------------" << "--------------------" << endl;

}

void ReadFile (fList, mList)
{

}
```

Comment: `void ReadFile (fList, mList)` You forgot types.

Comment: @chris: Or rather, forgot to ommit the return type.

Comment: @GManNickG, Oops, I didn't even spot that. I copied that from the function header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void ReadFile (fList, mList);
```

should be

```
void ReadFile (FemList fList, MaleList mList);
```

and

```
int main ()
{    
  FemList fList; // Array of Fem structs
  MaleList mList; // Array of Male structs

  void OutputHeader ();
  void ReadFile (fList, mList);    
}
```

should be

```
int main ()
{    
  FemList fList; // Array of Fem structs
  MaleList mList; // Array of Male structs

  OutputHeader ();
  ReadFile (fList, mList);    
}
```

Below code should be working. Note, I enhanced it a bit, not sure this is what you want?
1. provide full namespace for identifier from std
2. pass parameters by reference to ReadFile. Do you want to read file into FemList and MaleList, is that your intention?

```
/* Global named constants */
const int NUM_ANSWERS = 10;
const int NUM_STRUCTS = 15;

/* Global type definitions */

// Two struct types, Male and Female
struct Male
{
  int maleAnswers [NUM_ANSWERS];
  std::string name;
};

struct Fem
{
  int femAnswers [NUM_ANSWERS];
  std::string name;
};

// Arrays of structs
typedef Fem FemList [NUM_STRUCTS];
typedef Male MaleList [NUM_STRUCTS];

/* global function prototypes */
void OutputHeader ();
void ReadFile(FemList&, MaleList&);

int main ()
{

  FemList fList; // Array of Fem structs
  MaleList mList; // Array of Male structs

  OutputHeader();
  ReadFile(fList, mList);

}

void OutputHeader ()
{
  std::cout << "==================================================================" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Welcome to the Cheap & Ineffective Dating Service of Tallahassee!" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "                       eDisHarmony.com" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "==================================================================" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "<><><> Initial Client Data as Input <><><>" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::setw(11) << "Sex" << std::setw(31) << "Answers" << "Name" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::setw(11) << "---" << std::setw(24) << "-------------------" << "--------------------" << std::endl;
}

void ReadFile (FemList &fList, MaleList &mList)
{
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, I always want to declare them again for some reason.  It's still not compiling though.. It's still blaming it on my second struct again for some reason.

Comment: 1>c:\users\collin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\datingservice\datingservice\program6.cpp(62): error C2236: unexpected 'struct' 'Fem'. Did you forget a ';'? 

1>c:\users\collin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\datingservice\datingservice\program6.cpp(62): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' 

1>c:\users\collin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\datingservice\datingservice\program6.cpp(62): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Comment: It tells you that you are missing `;` somewhere around line 62

Comment: this is line 62
    "struct Fem"  
Should I put one there?  I thought it was after the }

Comment: You pretty much hit what I was trying to do on the head.  Could you explain the "std::" though? I have yet to use that in class.

Comment: It's preferable coding style, get less bugs etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I tried what you suggested but I keep getting this error telling me to put a ; after the line "struct Fem" .. I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: do you mean my updated code in my answer doesn't work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20543/discussion-between-billz-and-user1828561)

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the "void"s in main function, and use types for the function definition